# Retrofit POST запрос для регистрация API ?act=register&email={email}&fullname={fullname}&password={pas}

Tags: android, api, retrofit

API `?act=register&email={email}&fullname={fullname}&password={pas}`
выводить ошибку

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string
>   "act=register&email={email}&fullname={fullname}&password={pas}" must
>   not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
>                                                                                 for method ApiInterface.register
>                                                                                 at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:695)
>                                                                                 at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:686)
>                                                                                 at
>   retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseHttpMethodAndPath(ServiceMethod.java:296)
>                                                                                 at
>   retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseMethodAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:250)
>                                                                                 at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:169)
>                                                                                 at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
>                                                                                 at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
>                                                                                 at $Proxy0.register(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   project.avtopost.kz.kudakz.SignupActivity.attemptLogin(SignupActivity.java:208)
>                                                                                 at
>   project.avtopost.kz.kudakz.SignupActivity.access$000(SignupActivity.java:48)
>                                                                                 at
>   project.avtopost.kz.kudakz.SignupActivity$2.onClick(SignupActivity.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

не знаю как правильно написать Query

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@POST("?act=register&email={email}&fullname={fullname}&password={pas}")
Call<RegResponse> register(@Query ("email") String email , @Query("fullname") String fullname , @Query("pas") String password);
}

String name = mSignUpName.getText().toString();
            String pass = mSignUpPasswordView.getText().toString();
            email = mSignUpEmailView.getText().toString();

            ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<RegResponse> call = apiInterface.register(name,email,pass);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<RegResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RegResponse> call, Response<RegResponse> response) {
                    showProgress(false);
                    Log.d("Log","True");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RegResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    showProgress(false);
                    Log.d("Log","Error" + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

переменные аннотированные @Query подставляются в итоговую ссылку автоматически, не нужно писать `&email={email}` и т.д.

Comment: надо API писать вот так  @POST("?act=register&email&fullname&password")

Comment: а это, кстати, точно post запрос? А то выглядит как GET. будет @POST("?act=register")
Call<RegResponse> register(@Query ("act") String act, @Query ("email") String email , @Query("fullname") String fullname , @Query("pas") String password);   передавать act = register

Comment: @BagdatEshmuratov, по идее надо вот так: `@POST("?act=register")` - т.е. не указывать вовсе все те параметры, которые в аргументах передаются